# Zendframework Rowset select by key

Tags: php, database, zend-framework, zend-db

I'm trying to access rows of a fetchAll call (returns Zend_Db_Table_Rowset_Abstract) by a row's primary key.

I was wondering what would be the easiest way of doing this, besides looping through and finding the desired row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I recall correctly, `Zend_Db_Table_Rowset_Abstract` is just passed an array (or something that acts like one), then as you iterate through it, it creates the `Zend_Db_Table_Row_Abstract` objects.

The best way may be to loop through once, and store the rows in an array, indexed by the primary key. That way you do one loop, then can access any row by the key.

**Update**: Just took a look at the source, here's data that's (eventually) passed to the rowset object:

```
$stmt = $this->_db->query($select);
$data = $stmt->fetchAll(Zend_Db::FETCH_ASSOC);
return $data;
```

When you iterate through the rowset for the first time, that original array is used to create the row objects. The data hasn't been looped through before that point, so you're not doing something that's already been done.

So you have to do something like this to map rows to primary key (I haven't used `Zend_Db_*` for a while, treat this a pseudocode):

```
$rows = array();
foreach($rowset as $row){
  //you could pull the primary key from Zend_Db_Table
  $rows[$row->id] = $row;
}

//now you can lookup by primary key
$rows[55]->name;
```

Of course you can extend the abstract rowset class and do this internally if you want.

Comment: Thanks, I was afraid of doing too many loops but didn't think of this way.

Comment: @Gootik, if you're doing this alot (or in many different places), you should probably extend the rowset class make the access transparent.

Answer (score 1):

Use '$db->find($id)->current();'

Hope it helps.

Comment: That would hit the DB every time he accesses a row, since he's using `fetchAll`, I think it's fair to assume he wants to grab a large set of data to work with (not individual rows). He just wants to access those retrieved rows by primary key.

Comment: I see. So, with the code you provided we are able to access a row like: '$row = $data[$id];' Am I correct?

Comment: No, that code is internal to `Zend_Db_Table_Abstract` - it just shows that `$data` (which is passed to the `Zend_Db_Rowset_Abstract` constructor), is simply the result array from the Db driver (the index is not the primary key). There's no way to map primary key to the row unless you iterate through it - the thing to note is that the internal code doesn't do anything like that for you, so it's not a duplicate effort if you do it in your code.

Comment: Tim is correct, it's a huge data set and i just want to fetch them all at once and work on them later instead of making data calls for each row.